# I want draw on the video using mouse pointer in HTML5

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, html5-video

The aim is to able to write using mouse movement on video on pause.

I am using an HTML5 Video tag to play video.

I am able to play the video without any issue, apart from playing video I need to write able to draw on video on the pause of the video

I am able to write on canvas. But when I have a video tag in canvas, I am NOT able to view any of my drawings.

Can you please let me know, what I am doing wrong?

Below is the code:

```
<html>

<!-- <body onload="init()"> -->
<body> 
    <canvas id="can" width="400" height="400" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;">
    </canvas>
    
    <video id="can" width="400" height="400" style="position:absolute;top:10%;left:10%;border:2px solid;">
    <source src="Test.mp4" type="video/mp4">
    </video>
    
</body>
    
<script type="text/javascript">
    
    var canvas, ctx, flag = false,
        prevX = 0,
        currX = 0,
        prevY = 0,
        currY = 0,
        dot_flag = false;

    var x = "black",
        y = 2;
    
    //# must await page load via JS (before using JS functions)...
    addEventListener("load", init );
    
    function init() 
    {
        canvas = document.getElementById('can');
        ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        w = canvas.width;
        h = canvas.height;

        canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", function (e) { findxy('move', e)}, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mousedown", function (e) { findxy('down', e) }, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseup", function (e) { findxy('up', e)}, false);
        canvas.addEventListener("mouseout", function (e) { findxy('out', e)}, false);
    }

    function draw() 
    {
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(prevX, prevY);
        ctx.lineTo(currX, currY);
        ctx.strokeStyle = x;
        ctx.lineWidth = y;
        ctx.stroke();
        ctx.closePath();
    }

    function erase() 
    {
        var m = confirm("Want to clear");
        
        if (m) 
        {
            ctx.clearRect(0, 0, w, h);
            document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "none";
        }
    }

    function save() 
    {
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.border = "2px solid";
        
        //var dataURL = canvas.toDataURL();
        //document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = dataURL;
        
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").src = canvas.toDataURL();
        document.getElementById("canvasimg").style.display = "inline";
    }

    function findxy(res, e) 
    {
        if (res == 'down') 
        {
            prevX = currX;
            prevY = currY;
            currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
            currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;

            flag = true;
            dot_flag = true;
            
            if (dot_flag) 
            {
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.fillStyle = x;
                ctx.fillRect(currX, currY, 2, 2);
                ctx.closePath();
                dot_flag = false;
            }
        }
        
        if (res == 'up' || res == "out") 
        { flag = false; }
        
        if (res == 'move') 
        {
            if (flag) 
            {
                prevX = currX;
                prevY = currY;
                currX = e.clientX - canvas.offsetLeft;
                currY = e.clientY - canvas.offsetTop;
                draw();
            }
        }
    }
    
    function color(obj) 
    {
        switch (obj.id) 
        {
            case "green": x = "green"; break;
            case "blue": x = "blue"; break;
            case "red": x = "red"; break;
            case "yellow": x = "yellow"; break;
            case "orange": x = "orange"; break;
            case "black":
                x = "black";
                break;
            case "white":
                x = "white";
                break;
        }
        
        if (x == "white") y = 14;
        else y = 2;

    }

</script>
    
</html>
```

Comment: It's fairly difficult to help troubleshoot this without a working demo, but from the code that you provided, it looks like you have at least a `z-index` issue.  Have you tried setting the `z-index` of the `<canvas>` to a higher number than the `video` element (like 100)?

Comment: By the way -- from reading your code, I'm assuming that you want to save a capture of the video frame with the annotations from the user.  If this is the case, this code will probably not work as you expect. If so, you'll have to go a route like this: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Canvas_API/Manipulating_video_using_canvas

Comment: **(1)** Your code isn't drawing any video to canvas. **(2)** You are using same ID for both video and canvas elements as `can`, so your `getElementById('can')` might be getting `<video>` object instead of a `<canvas>`. Try useful ID names like `myCanvas` and `myVideo` when testing an idea or code.  **(3)** You don't have a `canvasimg` to get by ID... Maybe fixing these things might help towards solving your issue.

Comment: **PS:** I re-arranged your code for readability. It's a bit weird to read code that references things that don't exist until you scroll to the bottom, until that point everything else seems like a mistake that will cause error. Declare HTML elements first then write JS code to reference the _now existing_ elements. Use Javascript to detect a page load's completion and then run some JS functions.